# For each element in a vector, find the length of the interval (exclusive) between its preceding and following minimum

Tags: r

Consider the following vector:

```
Y <- c(2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2)
```

I need to create a loop which finds the largest element in a vector with the length of the interval (exclusive) between preceding and following element with a smaller value, IF there are at least as many elements between those two elements as the value of the currently examined element itself. If an element is not preceded or followed by an element with smaller value, we count all elements from that side. In my example I use variable `Z` to keep track of the biggest one we have found while we navigate through the vector.

```
# we start with Z <- 0
    .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
                ^
```

First value in our vector is `2`. There are no preceding numbers, and smaller following number is the marked `1`. The interval (exclusive) between the marked `1` and beginning of the vector is larger than the element we are examining right now (`2`), so we set the value of this element to `Z`. `Z <- 2`

```
# Z is now 2 from examining previous element
      .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
    ^   ^
```

Next element is `3`, and we search for preceding and following element smaller than `3`. They are marked above, and since there are only one element between them, we are not interested in this element further. There should be at least three elements between the `2`'s, since we are currently examining element of value `3`. No changes to `Z`.

```
# Z is still 2
        .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
                ^
```

If we optimize the code, we can straight away skip this `2`. `Z` is already `2`, so there is no way this element can change that to a bigger value, so we aren't really interested in proceeding further here. If we for some reason don't want to skip this, there are no preceding smaller element, and marked `1` is the following smaller element. Their interval is `6`, which is larger than the element we are currently examining, a `2`. We would set Z to match this element, if Z wasn't already matching this element. It is, so there are no changes.

```
# Z is still 2
          .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
        ^       ^
```

Next element is a `3`, and the preceding and following numbers are marked above. Their interval (exclusive) is `3` which is at least the value of the element we are currently examining, so we update `Z <- 3`.

```
# Z is now 3
            .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
          ^   ^
```

Next element is a `4`. Preceding and following elements that are smaller are marked above. Since their interval (exclusive) is less than `4` elements, we are not interested in this element further.

```
# Z is still 3
              .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
        ^       ^
```

Next element is a `3`. We can again skip this, since this element can't change the value of `Z`, since `Z` is already `3`.

```
# Z is still 3
                .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
```

Next element is a `1`. We can again skip this, since this element can't change the value of `Z`, since `Z` is already `3`.

```
# Z is still 3
                  .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
                ^   ^
```

Next element is a `7`. Immediately preceding and following elements are smaller than it, so we are not interested in this element further. There should be at least `7` elements between the two elements that have smaller value than the current one.

```
# Z is still 3
                    .
[1] 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
                ^
```

Next element is a `2`. We can again skip this, since this element can't change the value of `Z`, since `Z` is already `3`.

We have now gone through the whole vector, and we have found the largest element with length of the interval (exclusive) between preceding and following minimum at least as much as the element itself.

Now, I have a data set with several hundred thousand numbers, ranging from 1 to several thousands.

Comment: i am curious as to why you want to do this. Is it purely academic or is there a higher purpose?

Comment: This is easy if you let us know how we can determine which number has a `'.'` over it.

Comment: So can you rephrase this question to say 'for each element in a vector, I want to find the length of the interval (exclusive) between its preceding and following minimum?'

Comment: I updated the example so that it shows a step-by-step process going through the whole vector. Andrew, you are very close to what I need with that phrasing! I hope the example shines further light into this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a start:

```
dummy <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(y)) {

  b <- ifelse(min(y[1:i-1]) < y[i], i - max(which(y[1:i-1] == min(y[1:i-1]), T)), i)
  a <- ifelse(min(y[(i+1):length(y)]) < y[i], min(which(y[(i+1):length(y)] == min(y[(i+1):length(y)]), T)), length(y) - i)

  ln <- c(y[i], b,  a)

  dummy <- rbind(dummy, ln)

}
```

Pops out a `df` with three fields - the original vector, the number of spaces between each element and the nearest preceding minimum that's less than the current value, and the number of spaces between the current value and the nearest following minimum that's less than the current value.

Wrote this before your edit, and I'm not quite clear on how your Z should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the text that you have provided:

```
      .
2 3 2 3 4 3 1 7 2
```

The following code will do the trick in linear time, though I'm operating under the assumption that another vector is present to indicate the index of the target integer (perhaps you used `readLines()`):

```
dot <- c(' ', ' ', ' ','.',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')
Y <- c(2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2)

myBestGuess <- function(dot, y){
    tmp <- which(dot == '.')
    i <- tmp+1
    res <- 0
    while(i <= length(y)){
        if (y[i] <= y[tmp]){
            res <- res + 1
            i <- i + 1
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    i <- tmp-1
    while(i > 0){
        if (y[i] <= y[tmp]){
            res <- res + 1
            i <- i - 1
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return(res)
}

print(myBestGuess(dot, Y))
```

The output:

```
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split this operation into three pieces. First, you could calculate how far to the left you have to go before you find an element smaller than the element in the current position (assume there is a negative infinity to the left of the entire vector, so for instance the first element goes to the left one position before it finds a smaller value):

```
(left.dist <- sapply(seq_along(Y), function(i) 1+i-max(which(c(-Inf, head(Y, i-1)) < Y[i]))))
# [1] 1 1 3 1 1 3 7 1 2
```

Similarly, I would compute how far to the right you have to go before you find an element smaller than the element in the current position:

```
(right.dist <- sapply(seq_along(Y), function(i) min(which(c(tail(Y, -i), -Inf) < Y[i]))))
# [1] 6 1 4 3 1 1 3 1 1
```

The number of elements in the range of interest around each position is `left.dist + right.dist - 1` so finding the maximum value in your vector with a range of at least its value is a simple exercise in vector indexing:

```
max(Y[left.dist + right.dist - 1 >= Y])
# [1] 3
```